# How To calculate RSSI parameters in 3G and LTE

Tags: signal-theory, lte

I'm working on how to determine the distance using RSSI through LTE and 3G network, but I'm having a problem how to calculate the RSSI at a certain distance

Answer (score 2):

There's different kinds of signal strength indicators (at least in 4G, RSSI is the least helpful one, you want to understand RSRP and RSRQ), and they're well defined. Distance alone is not sufficient for that – it's about noise levels, and frequency-selectiveness of the channel, which is not a function of distance, but of the multipath environment.

So, I'm afraid you'll have to [read up on quality measures in wideband standards (especially 4G)](https://www.cablefree.net/wirelesstechnology/4glte/rsrp-rsrq-measurement-lte/). Whole-band total power alone really is not very helpful for knowing how well reception works for any specific receiver.